# How to set default swagger welcome page in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web, swagger, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created a Web Api, and I want to set default landing url as Swagger url i.e:- 
http://localhost:65347/swagger/ui/index

Comment: You need to add more information about your routing configuration, if you use WEB API2, if you want to change the default page in Visual Studio, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by adding below code in RouteConfig.cs

routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "swagger",
             routeTemplate: "",
             defaults: null,
             constraints: null,
             handler: new RedirectHandler((url => url.RequestUri.ToString()), "swagger"));

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most accurate answer, but I simply set the Startup URL in my project to the Swagger page. You'll have to make sure the path is correct when you deploy, but works great for me when debugging on my workstation.....

[image]